# Edited by versus Retagged by

Tags: feature-request, edits, tags

I see a lot of answers with "Edited by BLAH".  But I suspect those are actually just retags.  It would be nice to differentiate the type of change made.  Seeing both of "retagged by" and "edited by" would clutter the interface but just changing the text if the change was just an edit would be quite nice.

Comment: You can just click on the "Edited N [units of time] ago" bit, and it'll show you an edit history, so you can see what was changed, when, and how many times.

Comment: Concur .. having "re-tag" be separate from "edit" is a nice idea.

Comment: Wow, I just logged onto meta to ask this question and was going to search first to make sure it hadn't already been asked. Creepy.

Comment: Heh, this is the third question I came up with for meta.  After finding out the first two were already here I didn't hold out much hope for this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is a good idea, especially as users < 2000 rep only get a "retag" option rather than "edit". It would be nice to see that the edit was only a retagging without having to click through to the edit history.

Comment: It's users < 500 (not 2000) rep who get retag, considering that I have retag powers on Meta.

Comment: Yes, users under 2000 rep only get a "retag" option, is that not what I said?

Answer (score 4):

I try to make at least 10 edits per day, this would be helpful. Very often, I see that a question was 'edited', but still see things obviously wrong with spelling, grammar and punctuation.

This helps me to instantly see that a post was re-tagged, the things I see that are incorrect weren't missed by the last editor (purposefully or otherwise).

I'd also love if it could say "Rolled Back By .... ", just like "Re-Tagged By ...", which alerts me check to see if an edit war is going on prior to inadvertently joining the fray :)